# Getting java.lang.ClassCastException error while running robolectric using ant build using eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, ant, robolectric

Here I am facing the trouble while running robolectric test cases for android its saying j`ava.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassCastException:com.test.MyTestRunner cannot be cast to com.xtremelabs.robolectric.internal.RobolectricTestRunnerInterface`

**Note I am Using JUNIT 4.11 jar**

Comment: You're missing something from that stacktrace, what is it that cannot be cast? Could you please post the full stacktrace, the relevant code and the command you are using to run?

Comment: You are right i have edited please check.

Comment: Could you please add related code as well?

Comment: I fixed the problem here i am Posting it

Answer (score 0):

I found This `RobolectricTestInterface` is not working with `JUUNIT 4.11` jar so i used the the older version its working perfectly